# Python PropertyMock in Mock constructor

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm using Michael Foord's mock library and have a question about it.

I want to mock a property, so I do this:

```
eggs = mock.PropertyMock(return_value='eggs')
spam = mock.Mock()
type(spam).eggs = eggs
assert spam.eggs == 'eggs'
```

This works brilliantly. However I find the `type()` part ugly and would love to do something like this:

```
eggs = mock.PropertyMock(return_value='eggs')
spam = mock.Mock(eggs = eggs)
assert spam.eggs == 'eggs'
```

The last example doesn't work as expected, `spam.eggs` becomes a method instead of a property.

---

I know I can use `mock.Mock(eggs = 'eggs')` so `eggs` is not a method, but I want to be able to assert the property. :-)

---

I am using Python 2.7, but I assume `unittest.Mock` works too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The patch can help you to a degree, the code is taken from [official Mock document](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/mock.html#mock.PropertyMock)

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     @property
...     def foo(self):
...         return 'something'
...     @foo.setter
...     def foo(self, value):
...         pass
...
>>> with patch('__main__.Foo.foo', new_callable=PropertyMock) as mock_foo:
...     mock_foo.return_value = 'mockity-mock'
...     this_foo = Foo()
...     print this_foo.foo
...     this_foo.foo = 6
...
mockity-mock
>>> mock_foo.mock_calls
[call(), call(6)]
```

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution specific to `Mock`. However I have not been able to find one and `patch` seems to be the best solution. Because of this I will accept this answer.